# Keeping web application state between requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, backbone.js

I use Backbone.js for a project, in which I have a lot of view changing, and routing. When I change the view url, all of my "currentSession" data, such as the active user, etc. is gone. What I thought about doing is hashing that session every time when the Backbone router gets called and dump it in a cookie, which gets read when the view reloads, and the session state is kept alive until I close the browser or log out intentionally.

Is this currently the only or the best way? I will be glad to hear about the best practices in  keeping application state on the client.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using the HTML5 local storage API  to persist this session info from screen to screen.  Alternatively, you can work to avoid entire page refreshes.  Since you are already using Backbone routers, this shouldn't be so much of a stretch.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you can't 'hash' and retrieve the data, this is impossible as hashing means the original data is lost.

The ASP.Net Session object works exactly as it does in Webforms, so rely on that instead of constructing your own, [this will be a good start](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/57/session/).

Comment: I want the client to manage that, agnostic of the server infrastructure